# Proper repeat of API access

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reddit

I'd like to create a live feed for the front page of Reddit by the use of the API. Since it has very limited support for Websocket, I thought I'd use a sub-optimal solution: my program would get the most recent posts with a certain frequency and append some data of them to an HTML table.

To provide some code, here's a shortened version of what I'm doing:

```
//cliendID and clientSec are declared vars I omit for safety reasons
function Auth(callback){

  //Authorization to Reddit API
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token",

      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(
               "Authorization", 
               "Basic " + btoa(clientID + ":" + clientSec));
      },

      data:
        {
          grant_type: "client_credentials",
          user: clientID,
          password: clientSec
        },

      success: callback
  });
}

//params.listing and APIurl are also declared
function afterAuth(token){
    accessAPI(token, printResult, params.listing, APIurl);
}


//standardized Reddit API access
function accessAPI(response, callback, inputJSON, url){

  //console.log("accessAPI: "+response);

  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: /* an oauth.reddit.com link */,

      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", response.token_type + " " + response.access_token);
      },

      data: /* input necessary for that API request */

      success: callback
  });

};

//test function, for demonstration purposes
function printResult(querydat){
  console.log(querydat);
}
```

What my program does is a simple call: `Auth(afterAuth)`, where the chain follows:

- The POST AJAX request within `Auth`, if successful, calls `afterAuth`.
- `afterAuth` uses an identification token (if I remember correctly) as an input and functions as a "wrapper" to be able to run multiple API accesses.
- In this example, `accessAPI` is used for a GET AJAX request which directly accesses an oauth.reddit.com link, from which it fetch subreddit data.
- I manipulate this data through its success callback, which, here, is a simple demo function.

---

What I want to achieve is the periodic call of `accessAPI` so that it runs its callback on more recent posts as time goes on.

Because of the asynchronous nature of these calls (I presume), neither `setInterval` nor looped `setTimeout` seems to be a viable solution.

**What else can I do to produce this periodic call?**

(needless to say, repeated call of `Auth()` is impractical, but I can't see, how can I manipulate the inner flow otherwise.)

Comment: whats wrong with using `setInterval`? how often data need to be refreshed?

Comment: @JAG in theory, it doesn't really work out well with async calls. In practice, though, it doesn't repeat the calls, apparently, but stop after one run.

Comment: i dont know what you mean `it doesn't repeat the calls,...` i have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7ty4Lph/) with `setTimeout`

Comment: @JAG I could solve the problem since, refer to an answer. As an extra, though, thanks for your fiddle, it showed that I failed because I forgot calling the function within another, nameless function, when I used setInterval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a solution meanwhile.

The key was adding some "flow control" into `accessAPI` by using a plus input, `repeat`.

The AJAX call itself is now in a different function within the scope of `accessAPI`, so `setInterval` repeats the separate function.

```
function accessAPI(access_token, callback, inputJSON, url, repeat){


    if(repeat==0){ accessAPI_Execute();
            }else{ setInterval(accessAPI_Execute, repeat*1000)};


    //local function for setInterval() control
    function accessAPI_Execute(){

        //console.log("sending request...");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,

            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", access_token.token_type + " " + access_token.access_token);
            },

            data: inputJSON,

            success: callback
        })
    };

};
```

Unless any better solution comes, I consider it the accepted one.